# flutter custom appbar vertical position relative to status bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I used the example in the following [link](https://mightytechno.com/flutter-custom-appbar/) to create a custom appBar.

The code works, however the appbar is positioned at the top of the screen behind the Android status bar

How can I position the appBar such that it starts rendering **under** the status bar?

version used:

- Flutter 1.26.0-8.0.pre • channel dev
- Android R30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a widget called [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) that set the padding of your widget to avoid the intrusion of the status bar. You can use it as:

```dart
// Use the SafeArea here to position the AppBar under the status bar
SafeArea( 
   child: Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 100),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(

          // ... other lines
```